# How to Dynamically change the value of a text field when cloned

Tags: jquery, clone

I am cloning a portion of my form. The section has a dynamically assigned text field that when cloned I would like to automatically change to reflect the fact that it is a cloned section.

Script assigning ID to text field

```
 <script>

$("input[name='SiteVisitCode']").on('change', function(){
  var SVCode = document.getElementById('SiteVisitCode');
          $('#SampleID').val(SVCode.value +"-W");
          $("#QASampleID").val(SVCode.value +"-QC-FB");
          $("#Template").val(SVCode.value +"-FDW");
 </script>
```

html

```
     <div>  Site Visit Code<input type="text" name="SiteVisitCode" id="SiteVisitCode">    </div>
  <fieldset>
  <div id="template">
  <div>Sample ID: <input type="text" id="SampleID" name="SampleID"></div>
        <select id="Analysis" multiple name="Analysis" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <OPTION>Analysis (Select all that apply)</OPTION>
     <option value ="ABF">Anions, Bromide, Fluoride -- None -- Ice</option>
 </select>
 </div><!--template-->
 </fieldset>
 <input type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="FieldDup" value="ADD FIELD DUP">
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
```

clone script

```
  <script>
  $(function () {
   $('#FieldDup').on("click", function () {
   $('#template').clone(true).prependTo('#placeholder');
    });
  })

 </script>
```

I am looking to change the assigned `sampleID` and apply the assigned value identified by `$("#Template").val(SVCode.value +"-FDW")` to the cloned `SampleID`.

Comment: With this you are duplicating the id, instead assign a classname to your input.

Comment: Where do I assign the class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that you are duplicating the ID and trying to target it again. But the issue is that you can't target the ID because it is now being using on the page twice, which will cause the `.val()` binding to fail.

I believe one syntax that my work for this is:

```
$('#template').clone(function() {
    $(this).val(SVCode.value +"-FDW")
}).prependTo('#placeholder');
```

This will target the particular `#template` and set its value.

Comment: It didn't work but I feel I'm getting closer - thanks!